# iAD size is portrait in landscape

Tags: ios, iad

I want to implement an iAd at the bottom of my screen. My app runs in landscape mode only, but the iAd is in portrait mode, its too big and I want it correct.

I instantiate it with this :

ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 480, 32)];

```
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

So i give it 480 x 32 but it is in 360x 50.

That makes no sense to me and I don't know what to do. In the other topic I read I have to disable Auto Layout, but it is disabled.

thanks for any help!

edit: even if I add the iAd via storyboard to the view in landscape format, it shows it in portrait format when i run the app.

edit: I think I don't have a ADBannerView Appdelegate method. 
All I have for my iAd is : 
GameViewcontroller.h

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

GameViewcontroller.m

```
@interface GameViewController ()
{
BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
ADBannerView *_adBanner;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc]      initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width /2) - 180,       self.view.frame.size.height, 480, 32)];
_adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
```

}

```
 - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!_bannerIsVisible)
{
    // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
    if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

    // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -  banner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
```

}

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:    (NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

if (_bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

    // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0,  banner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to accomplish this programmatically or with Auto Layout? Please add your `ADBannerView` delegate method code also.

Comment: I added the code i use for iAd. I don't get why the Ad is in portrait mode and not in landscape :(.

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32101699/2108547). Just remove the `UITabBar` implementation.

Comment: I have changed the CGRectMake to this: _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, _adBanner.frame.size.height)];

the banner takes the full width of the screen and the height is fixed. So my banner is now 667x32. But in landscape mode it should be 480x32 doesn't it? If it doesn't matter if the ad is a big bigger than it should, I'm happy with this .

Comment: That is what it should be. Glad you could solve your problem. Up vote my other answer if it helped. Thank you.